# Programmatically getting solution details

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there a a way to get the processor type, build type, etc, from a Visual Studio solution, via C#?

Comment: do you from sln file or inside your code?

Comment: These are details of msbuild .targets files, not of a solution.  Moreover, a solution often contains multiple platform targets.  Which ultimately makes your question unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something called [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.configurationmanager%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which takes care of the build type and other details.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Visual Studio Addin (A Project Template is available in Visual Studio in the Extensibility Category) and access your current Solution Configuration with the ActionConfiguration Property from DTE.Solution. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.configurationmanager.activeconfiguration.aspx) for further details: